# How to read a web page, as a stream of lines, using akka-http 2.4.6

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I've done a sample project in GitHub: [akauppi/akka-2.4.6-trial](https://github.com/akauppi/akka-2.4.6-trial)

What I want seems simple: read a URL, provide the contents as a line-wise stream of `String`s. Now I've struggled with this (and reading documentation) for the whole **day** so decided to push the sample public and ask for help.

I'm comfortable with Scala. I know Akka, and last time I've used Akka-streams it was probably pre-2.4. Now, I'm lost.

**Questions:**

On these [lines](https://github.com/akauppi/akka-2.4.6-trial/blob/master/src/main/scala/Sample.scala#L27-L39) I'd like to return a `Source[String,Any]`, not a `Future` (note: those lines do not compile).

The problem probably is that `Http().singleRequest(...)` materialises the flow, and I don't want that. How to just inject the "recipe" of reading a web page without actually reading it?

```
 def sourceAsByteString(url: URL)(implicit as: ActorSystem, mat: Materializer): Source[ByteString, Any] = {
    import as.dispatcher

    val req: HttpRequest = HttpRequest( uri = url.toString )

    val tmp: Source[ByteString, Any] = Http().singleRequest(req).map( resp => resp.entity.dataBytes )   // does not compile, gives a 'Future'
    tmp
  }
```

Comment: Pull requests to the repo are appreciated, or just advice here.

Comment: So you assume that the content is text/plain?

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn Yes. It's actually JSON but I want to parse it line-wise (each line is a JSON object by itself)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the chunks you get from the server are not lines, but might be anything. You will often get small responses in a single chunk. So you have to split the stream to lines yourself.

Something like this should work:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.client.RequestBuilding._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")

implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

val delimiter: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] =
  Framing.delimiter(
    ByteString("\r\n"),
    maximumFrameLength = 100000,
    allowTruncation = true)

import system.dispatcher

val f = Http().singleRequest(Get("http://www.google.com")).flatMap { res =>
  val lines = res.entity.dataBytes.via(delimiter).map(_.utf8String)
  lines.runForeach { line =>
    println(line)
  }
}

f.foreach { _ =>
  system.terminate()
}
```

Note that if you wanted to return the lines instead of printing them, you would end up with a `Future[Source[String, Any]]`, which is unavoidable because everything in akka-http is async. You could "flatten" this to a `Source[String, Any]` that produces no elements in case of a failed request, but that would probably not be a good idea.

To get a "recipe" for reading a web page, you could use `Http().outgoingConnection("http://www.google.com")`, which creates a `Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[OutgoingConnection]]`, so a thing where you put in `HttpRequest` objects and get back `HttpResponse` objects.

Comment: Thanks. The paragraph below the code may help me understand where I'm seeing the world wrong. Maybe it's the exposure to how Rx does streaming - there a stream can carry error information, so flattening to `Source[String,Any]` would be completely appropriate, and actually the right thing. I need to learn to think in Akka, without forgetting how Rx works when I'm in that land.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem probably is that `Http().singleRequest(...)` materialises
>   the flow, and I don't want that.

That was indeed at the heart of the problem. There are two ways to start:

`Http().singleRequest(...)` leads to a Future (i.e. materializes the stream, already in the very beginning).

`Source.single(HttpRequest(...))` leads to a Source (non-materialized).

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/client-side/connection-level.html#connection-level-api

Ideally, such an important difference would be visible in the names of the methods used, but it's not. One simply has to know it, and understand the two above approaches are actually vastly different.

- @RüdigerKlaehn's answer covers the linewise cutting pretty well, but also see the [Cookbook](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Parsing_lines_from_a_stream_of_ByteStrings)
- when dealing with a `Source`, use `mapConcat` in place of the `flatMap` (Futures), to flatten the `res.entity.dataBytes` (which is an inner stream). Having these two levels of streams (requests, then chunks per request) adds to the mental complexity especially since we only have one of the outer entities.

There might still be some simpler way, but I'm not looking at that actively any more. Things work. Maybe once I become more fluent with akka streams, I'll suggest a further solution.

Answer (score 0):

Code for reading an HTTP response, linewise (akka-http 1.1.0-RC2):

```
val req: HttpRequest = ???

val fut: Future[Source[String,_]] = Http().singleRequest(req).map { resp =>
  resp.entity.dataBytes.via(delimiter)
    .map(_.utf8String)
}
```

`delimiter` as in @Rüdiger-klaehn's answer.